# elementary OS freya wireless constantly disconnects

Tags: release-freya, wifi

hi i'm having a wifi issue, i have win7 and ElementaryOs (ubuntu 14.04) on my toshiba satellite c55-c5206s with a broadcom BCM943142Y and the wifi randomly disconnects, it doesnt happen while im in windows. Linux is updated.

what i found, broadcom drivers are a little broken, and when wifi signal drop down from 55% the wireless constantly disconnects.

help please, i really want to start using linux full time

```
Hw Info

    > lspci -knn | grep Net  -A2  

    07:00.0 Network controller [0280]:
    > Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) 
    >   Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. Device [1b9a:3002]   Kernel driver
    > in use: wl 

    > sudo lspci -knn  

    00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation
    > Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 0b)      Subsystem: Toshiba
    > America Info Systems Device [1179:f840]  00:02.0 VGA compatible
    > controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics
    > Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info
    > Systems Device [1179:f840]    Kernel driver in use: i915  00:03.0 Audio
    > device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller
    > [8086:0a0c] (rev 0b)      Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device
    > [1179:f840]   Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel  00:14.0 USB
    > controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31]
    > (rev 04)      Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f840] 
    >   Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd  00:16.0 Communication controller
    > [0780]: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04) 
    >   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f840]      Kernel
    > driver in use: mei_me  00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation
    > 8 Series HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)     Subsystem: Toshiba
    > America Info Systems Device [1179:f840]   Kernel driver in use:
    > snd_hda_intel  00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series
    > PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)      Kernel driver in use:
    > pcieport  00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI
    > Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)      Kernel driver in use:
    > pcieport  00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI
    > Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)      Kernel driver in use:
    > pcieport  00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI
    > Express Root Port 6 [8086:9c1a] (rev e4)      Kernel driver in use:
    > pcieport  00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 8 Series
    > USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)      Subsystem: Toshiba America Info
    > Systems Device [1179:f840]    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci  00:1f.0
    > ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller
    > [8086:9c45] (rev 04)      Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device
    > [1179:f840]   Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich  00:1f.2 SATA controller
    > [0106]: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
    > [8086:9c03] (rev 04)      Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device
    > [1179:f840]   Kernel driver in use: ahci  00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel
    > Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04) 
    >   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f840]  07:00.0
    > Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
    > [14e4:4365] (rev 01)      Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. Device
    > [1b9a:3002]   Kernel driver in use: wl  08:00.0 Ethernet controller
    > [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express
    > Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)     Subsystem:
    > Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f840]   Kernel driver in
    > use: r8169  09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor
    > Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01) 
    >   Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:f840]      Kernel
    > driver in use: rtsx_pci
    > - Device: wlan0  [#$%#$%#$%$%] ------------------------------------------------    Type:              802.11 WiFi    Driver:            wl    State:             connected    Default:           yes    HW Address:        #$%#$%#$%#$%#$
    > 
    >   Capabilities: 
    >     Speed:           72 Mb/s 
    > 
    >   Wireless Properties 
    >     WEP Encryption:  yes 
    >     WPA Encryption:  yes 
    >     WPA2 Encryption: yes 
    > 
    >   Wireless Access Points (* = current AP) 
    >     *%#$%#$%#$%:   Infra, #$%#$%#$%$#%$#%, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 57 WPA2 
    > 
    >   IPv4 Settings: 
    >     Address:         192.168.1.101 
    >     Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0) 
    >     Gateway:         192.168.1.2 
    > 
    >     DNS:             192.168.1.2 
    > 
> - lshw
> *-network 
>                 description: Ethernet interface 
>                 product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller 
>                 vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
>                 physical id: 0 
>                 bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0 
>                 logical name: eth0 
>                 version: 07 
>                 serial: #$%#$%#%$%#$
>                 size: 10Mbit/s 
>                 capacity: 100Mbit/s 
>                 width: 64 bits 
>                 clock: 33MHz 
>                 capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd
> autonegotiation 
>                 configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half
> firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
> port=MII speed=10Mbit/s 
>                 resources: irq:46 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2404000-a2404fff memory:a2400000-a2403fff
> memory:8fb00000-8fb0ffff
> 
> 
> -
> 
-

> sudo iwconfig  eth0      no wireless extensions. 
> 
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any   
>           Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=200 dBm    
>           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off 
>           Encryption key:off 
>           Power Management:off 
>             bridge0   no wireless extensions. 
> 
> lo        no wireless extensions.
list of solutions i try:

apt-get update

apt-get upgrade

http://askubuntu.com/a/734963/509282

http://askubuntu.com/a/129634/509282
```

-

```
 sudo rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

update:

i tested the conection with the router right beside me and still i have an unstable conection.

people with the same problem:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/having-some-wifi-erratic-behavior

[WiFi connection dropping](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/wifi-connection-dropping)

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3895/lose-wifi-signal-about-4-5-times-a-day

Comment: This is a problem with broadcom.Change the laptop WiFi card to non broadcom

Comment: Share the output of: sudo rfkill list all

Comment: so you are telling that i need to change my wifi card to have a stable internet in linux, while in win7 i have a perfect and stable conection?

Comment: can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you tried sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source ??

Comment: yes, i have tried that too

Comment: And then sudo modprobe wl??

Comment: yes i did, the wifi works, but the problem is that the wifi is very unstable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after days searching for a solution, no solution found so far, so i give up.

Comment: Replace the WiFi card with Intel :)

Comment: It happens with Intel chips too.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same issue with my Dell Inspiron N5010 and the Broadcomm Wireless Adapter. There's a bug report where you can add some piece of information about the problem: https://bugs.launchpad.net/elementaryos/+bug/1080959.

Regards!

Comment: I also gave up. Linux mint worked like a charm ;-)